# rselenium screenshot display different from the actual

Tags: dropdown, screenshot, rselenium

I'm working with aspx website (https://legistar.council.nyc.gov/Calendar.aspx) and would like to select a certain value from a dropdown menu and scrape a resulting table. But when I navigate to the website and display the front page using screenshot(), the default dropdown menu is different from what I actually see in *Chrome*:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(port=4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$getStatus()
remDr$navigate("https://legistar.council.nyc.gov/Calendar.aspx")
remDr$screenshot(display = T)
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                  value = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tdYears']")$clickElement()
```

The ultimate goal is to click on 'All Years', click 'Search Calendar' and scrape the whole table, but I can't even get the timeframe dropdown list to select 'All Years', which I think is caused by the discrepancy between what I actually see and how *rSelenium* sees it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved the issue

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                 value = '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstYears_Arrow"]')$clickElement()
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                  value = '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstYears_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[1]')$clickElement()
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath',
                  value = '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch"]')$clickElement()
```